# how do I select one (or several) dates in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe info is below.
I would like to create another dataframe selecting only dates=1997-5.
In SAS this would be done  using "where" command...
Can you please help?

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 264 entries, 0 to 263
Data columns (total 8 columns):
Dates        264 non-null datetime64[ns]
```

I tried doing:

```
may_97=returns_full[returns_full['Dates']='1997-05']
```

but got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` is for checking for equality. You can't do assignment whilst trying to apply a filter, as you are doing in `returns_full['Dates']='1997-05'`

Comment: Equally, you won't be able to compare `datetime64[ns]` to a string and get the kind of equality check you would like. You've given scant information here so it's not overly simple to help. Please give a [mcve]

Comment: thank you very much. That is the answer I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to select only the specified dates:

```
#suppose this is your first dataframe
N=60
df1=pd.DataFrame({'no': np.linspace(0, stop=N-1, num=N),
                 'date': pd.date_range(start='1997-4-1',periods=N, freq='D')})
print(df1)

#This is your second dataframe that is only select the dates that you want
df2=df1[(df1.date.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))).str.match('1997-05')]
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
#first dataframe
      no       date
0    0.0 1997-04-01
1    1.0 1997-04-02
2    2.0 1997-04-03
3    3.0 1997-04-04
4    4.0 1997-04-05
5    5.0 1997-04-06
...
56  56.0 1997-05-27
57  57.0 1997-05-28
58  58.0 1997-05-29
59  59.0 1997-05-30

#second dataframe
      no       date
30  30.0 1997-05-01
31  31.0 1997-05-02
32  32.0 1997-05-03
...
57  57.0 1997-05-28
58  58.0 1997-05-29
59  59.0 1997-05-30
```